# should d3 drag (v5) update object datum during dragging?

Tags: d3.js, drag

I'm dragging a single rectangle ... it drags correctly the first time, but the second time it jumps back to its starting point at the start of the drag.

I notice many drag examples on the net drag circles, where there is a fortunate correspondance between the point and the cx, cy. But with a rectangle there is an offset, which looks like it is supposed to be handled using the objects data. But I'm not sure exactly how.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<style>
svg {
        background-color: linen;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
        <svg id="svgc" width="450" height="450">
        </svg>
        <script>
        d3.select("#svgc").selectAll("rect")
                .data([{x: 100, y:200}])
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x",function(d) {return d.x; })
                .attr("y",function(d) {return d.y; })
                .attr("width",40)
                .attr("height",80)
                .attr("fill","steelblue");

        makeDragDrop();
function makeDragDrop() {
        var widget=undefined, color=undefined;
        var dragR=d3.drag()
                .on("start", function() {
                        color=d3.select(this).attr("fill");
                        widget=d3.select(this).attr("fill","lime");
                })
                .on("drag", function(d) {
                        d3.select(this)
                        .attr("x",d3.event.x)
                        .attr("y",d3.event.y);
                })
                .on("end", function() {
                        widget.attr("fill",color);
                        widget=undefined;
                })
        dragR(d3.select("#svgc").selectAll("rect"));
}
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does updating the datum like so: .`attr("x",d.x = d3.event.x).attr("y", d.y =d3.event.y)` not achieve what you are looking for?

Comment: It does indeed ... many thanks. I'm still a little confused about why ... because the event.x is the mouse value which will be offset a little from the object x (upper left).

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49179662/7106086

Comment: Wonderful, that explains everything. Many thanks.