# How to find x position of a combined g /svg element after drag

Tags: d3.js, observable, drag

I've appended an svg container inside a g element and then appended a rect.  I can transform and translate the g element into position which also positions the svg and rectangle.   The g element has a drag function but event.x for the drag always starts at 0 and then goes negative for drag to the left.  How can I access .attr("x") for the g element?  I need to find the screen position for the start of the g element to pass onto another function.

I add the `g` elements as follows:

```
  .join(function (group) {
        var gEnter = group.append("g")
         .attr("class", "rectangles")
         .append("svg")
         .attr("class", "container"); 
        ...
```

I position my `g` elements and call the drag function like so:

```
   svg.selectAll(".rectangles")
       .attr("transform", function (d, i) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";})
       ...
       .call(d3.drag().on("dragged", dragged)...);
```

Then I call the drag function on those `g` elements and update that position in the drag function:

```
function dragged(event, d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", function (d, i) {return "translate(" + event.x + "," + event.y + ")";})   
  }
```

Comment: What does your drag function look like and how to you position the original g?

Comment: I've created an example here https://observablehq.com/@steve-pegg/example-of-issue-with-positioning-on-repeat-drag     The issue here is when a rect is dragged more than once the drag always starts from the original coordinates  not the rect current position.  Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating your datum to reflect the new position. You need to update d.x and d.y:

```
function dragged(event, d) {
    d.x = event.x; d.y = event.y; // update the datum.
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", function (d, i) {return "translate(" + event.x + "," + event.y + ")";})   
  }
```

By default, the drag subject is the datum, using `d.x` and `d.y` to represent the x,y coordinate of the thing being dragged. The drag is relative to this - one pixel right is `d.x+1` regardless of where the mousedown event was. So if you never update the datum, each new drag event will be relative to the initial starting point.

If you want the screen position after the drag, that's `d.x` and `d.y`, if you update the datum throughout the drag:

```js
var svg  = d3.select("svg");

var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .datum({x: 100, y:100})
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+[d.x,d.y]+")"; })
  .call(d3.drag().on("drag", function(event,d) {
    d.x = event.x, d.y = event.y;
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+[d.x,d.y]+")"; });
    console.log("x: ", d.x);
  }))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg><svg>
```

*Note that `d` doesn't necessarily hold the screen position, but the position in SVG coordinate space*

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49179662/7106086) may also be useful.

Comment: Perfect.   Thank you.